# How to store a "set" (the python type) in a database efficiently?

Tags: python, sql, json, postgresql, pickle

I would like to store a "set" in a database (specifically PostgreSQL) efficiently, but I'm not sure how to do that efficiently.

There are a few options that pop to mind:

- store as a list (`{'first item', 2, 3.14}`) in a text or binary column.  This has the downside of requiring parsing when inserting into the database and pulling out.  For sets of text strings only, this seems to work pretty well, and the parsing is minimal.  For anything more complicated, parsing becomes difficult.
- store as a pickle in a binary column.  This seems like it should be quick, and it is complete (anything picklable works), but isn't portable across languages.
- store as json (either as a binary object or a text stream).  Larger problems than just plain text, but better defined parsing.

Are there any other options?  Does anyone have any experience with these?

Answer (score 2):

What you want to do is store a one-to-many relationship between a row in your table and the members of the set.

None of your solutions allow the members of the set to be queried by SQL. You can't do something like `select * from mytable where 'first item' in myset`. Instead you have to retrieve the text/blob and use another programming language to decode or parse it. That means if you want to do a query on the elements of the set you have to do a full table scan every time.

I would be very reluctant to let you do something like that in one of *my* databases.

I think you should break out your set into a separate table. By which I mean (since that is clearly not as obvious as I thought), one row per set element, indexed over *primary key of the table you are referring from* or, if you want to enforce no duplicates at the cost of a little extra space, *primary key of the table you are referring from* + *set element value*.

Since your set elements appear to be of heterogeneous types I see no harm in storing them as strings, as long as you normalize the numbers somehow.

Comment: At last count, the set of all sets has 600k elements.  It isn't really feasible to break that out into different columns, is it?

Comment: I see no problem with a table of 600K rows. If you are concerned about space efficiency (that was not clear from your question) then I think yourJSON proposal would be likely to take nearly as much space.

Comment: Regarding the number of elements, do you have 600k *distinct* elements? If not and you are concerned about table space (or want to avoid redundancy), you could just store a list of IDs in a joining table. I second @BoarGules arguments, if possible try to keep SQL data manageable in SQL (JSON is a PITA, but storing data in binary form is a definitice no-go) for me.

Comment: OP said "set of all sets has 600k elements," so I reckon that means distinct. So we can reckon on a table of about 1MB per byte of average element length. Not scary.

Answer (score 1):

One of the possible way is a JSONB arrays. Its able to store any types of elements and it could be indexed to improve the search speed:

```
create table t as
  select '["first item", 2, 3.14]'::jsonb as x
  from generate_series(1,100000);
insert into t values('["second item", 3, 2.72]');
create index idx on t using gin(x);

explain analyse select * from t where x @> '3';
┌───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│                                                  QUERY PLAN                                                   │
╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╡
│ Bitmap Heap Scan on t  (cost=36.78..327.18 rows=100 width=47) (actual time=0.055..0.056 rows=1 loops=1)       │
│   Recheck Cond: (x @> '3'::jsonb)                                                                             │
│   Heap Blocks: exact=1                                                                                        │
│   ->  Bitmap Index Scan on idx  (cost=0.00..36.75 rows=100 width=0) (actual time=0.028..0.028 rows=1 loops=1) │
│         Index Cond: (x @> '3'::jsonb)                                                                         │
│ Planning time: 0.188 ms                                                                                       │
│ Execution time: 0.121 ms                                                                                      │
└───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘

explain analyse select * from t where x @> '[3, "second item"]';
┌───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│                                                  QUERY PLAN                                                   │
╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╡
│ Bitmap Heap Scan on t  (cost=68.78..359.18 rows=100 width=47) (actual time=0.087..0.089 rows=1 loops=1)       │
│   Recheck Cond: (x @> '[3, "second item"]'::jsonb)                                                            │
│   Heap Blocks: exact=1                                                                                        │
│   ->  Bitmap Index Scan on idx  (cost=0.00..68.75 rows=100 width=0) (actual time=0.048..0.048 rows=1 loops=1) │
│         Index Cond: (x @> '[3, "second item"]'::jsonb)                                                        │
│ Planning time: 0.248 ms                                                                                       │
│ Execution time: 0.187 ms                                                                                      │
└───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

**Disadvantages:**

- There is no ready to use function/operator to delete element by value, only by index.
- There is no ready to use way to check elements uniqueness, you will need create it by yourself.

Links:
[JSON Types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-json.html)
[jsonb Indexing](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-json.html#JSON-INDEXING)
[JSON Functions and Operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html)